# Batch file read a line set values between spaces

Tags: file, text, batch-file, lines, spaces

I want to set up this batch file to read lines in a text file
using something along the lines of this.

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (RawData.txt) do (
set /a N+=1
set v!N!=%%a
)
```

and say for example the line it was reading was something along the lines of this.

```
20120901 0:00 9
```

I want it to set 3 different values now

```
value1 = 20120901
value2 = 0:00
value3 = 9
```

assuming every single line in the text file has 3 different strings in it. I want to set values between the 2 spaces.

Comment: Have you read the FOR documentation? (type `HELP FOR` from command prompt). You need to set the "tokens" option appropriatly. `"tokens=1,2,3"` would give the values in `%a` `%b` and `%c`. `"tokens=2"` would give the 2nd value in `%a`

Answer (score 0):

You're already pretty close.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set N=0
for /f "tokens=1-3" %%a in (RawData.txt) do (
    set /a N=!N!+1
    call set v!N!=%%a
    set /a N=!N!+1
    call set v!N!=%%b
    set /a N=!N!+1
    call set v!N!=%%c
)
```

I think.  I didn't test it.  You'll end up with `%v1%` through `%v3%` for the first line in RawData.txt, `%v4%` through `%v6` for the second, and so on.